# Unable To Convert C# Encryption/Hashing into Java Encryption/Hashing for Android

Tags: java, c#, android, encryption, hash

i currently have a code for making hashes for my website which hashes with SALT so the password is non reversible...

currently it is 100% working for my website which is coded using ASP.NET(C#)

here is my code

```
public string SaltedHash(string password)
{
    Salt = RandomString;
    Hash = ComputeHash(Salt, password);
    return Hash;
}
static string ComputeHash(string salt, string password)
{
    var saltBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(salt);
    using (var rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, saltBytes, 1000))
    {
        return Convert.ToBase64String(rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(256));
    }
}
```

and the way i use it when iam logging in is i get the stored SALT from the account in the database, and use that SALT for the current "ComputeHash"

and after i got a computed hash, i just check if that matches the hash on the database...

Example: Password = SaltedHash(PasswordTxt);

and then i just compare it to my current hash using SQL Queries, and it works 100%

FYI - All the SALT's are randomly generated and stored in the database

now... iam making an android app which uses the exact same thing, but unfortunately, whenever i try to make it work, it gives me a different HASH

here is my current code

```
public String SaltedHash(String password)
{
    Hash = new String(ComputeHash(password.toCharArray(), Salt.getBytes()));
    return Hash;
}
public static byte[] ComputeHash(char[] password, byte[] salt)
{
    PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, 1000, 256);
    Arrays.fill(password, Character.MIN_VALUE);
    try
    {
        SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        return skf.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e)
    {
        throw new AssertionError("Error while hashing a password: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    finally
    {
        spec.clearPassword();
    }
}
```

this one is designed to work exactly the same way, but unfortunately, i keep getting a different HASH for some reason, can someone help me out and point out what is wrong with my java code?

This has taken me 2weeks already and i still can't make it work properly.... And i DO NOT want to change/modify the C# code... Due to High Amount of Currently Hashed Passwords in the database...

**UPDATE**

i forgot to mention that my SALT SIZE is "70"

this is the code i use to generate a random salt in C#

```
void GenerateRandomSalt()
{
    //Create and populate random byte array
    byte[] randomArray = new byte[70];

    //Create random salt and convert to string
    RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    rng.GetBytes(randomArray);
    RandomString = Convert.ToBase64String(randomArray);
}
```

**UPDATE**

i did a little tweak with the JAVA code, and now the HASH looks a lot more similar to the Hash produced by C#, it is just not that accurate, i will be working a little bit more

```
public String SaltedHash(String password)
{
    Hash = new String(Base64.encodeToString(ComputeHash(password.toCharArray(), Salt.getBytes()), Base64.DEFAULT));
    return Hash;
}
```

Comment: *"Example: Password = SaltedHash(PasswordTxt);"* - Well it should be at least `==` instead of `=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(256)` means that you get 256 **bytes**. `new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, 1000, 256)` means that you get 256 **bits**.

Change it to `rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(32)`, because 256 bytes is so large that the security improvements might actually be negative. It would be far more important to implement a constant-time comparison function between the calculated hash and the stored hash. If you don't, it might be possible to brute-force the password.

The other issue is that you're decoding the salt from Base64 in C# (`var saltBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(salt);`), but you're using the *default character encoding* (probably UTF-8) to decode the salt in Java (`Salt.getBytes()`). You have to use the same decoding which means that you have to decode from Base64 in Java.

Comment: is there any way that i can just change the bytes on the PBEKeySpec instead? because if i change the one on C#, that would affect thousands of passwords that are already hashed, thanks for the effort tho :) now atleast i got an idea might be causing the mismatch, no worries ;) im not down voting this ;)

Comment: i tried changing the new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, 1000, 2048), but it is giving me a new error, it is really odd, 2048bits = 256bytes right?

Comment: @GabrielValdezTimbol You should tell us the new error.

Comment: i get an error with my SQL query and it says i got a "Syntax Error" so, to narrow it down, i tried to just get the HASH given by java and see if it matches with the C# hash manually, but unfortunately, the Java HASH is 100% off, plus it has a lot of "?"

Comment: i tried doing a "TEST RUN" on lowering down the bytes of the C# code to 32, unfortunately, when i do that, the Hashes still do not match for some reason, the Java hash is still too short, i just tried it in a testing environment to check if it will yield atleast a little good output

Comment: Here's a [proof-of-concept gist](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/7164a503945c4993113cb984c884fe5b). It contains runnable code and produces the same results in C# and Java. If you cannot change the C# code, then you will have to change the output size in Java.

Comment: I noticed, you're using `Salt.getBytes()`. The salt should be decoded from Base64 according to your C# code instead.

Comment: i tried updating it! decoded the salt first :) i got the answer i needed! please update your answer and i will tag it as the right one :)